# Connect IncrementalProjectBuilder to Generic Project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

**What I want:** I'm developing an Eclipse editor plug-in. I want to be able to build a project, which was created by "New... -> Project... -> General -> Project". This should project should be built automatically.

**What I have:** I extended the `IncrementalProjectBuilder` class:

```
public class GenericProjectBuilder extends IncrementalProjectBuilder {

  /**
   * @see org.eclipse.core.resources.IncrementalProjectBuilder#build(int, java.util.Map, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)
   */
  @Override
  protected IProject[] build(int arg0, Map<String, String> arg1, IProgressMonitor arg2) throws CoreException {
    DIService.getInstance(ModelStateAssembler.class).scheduleFullRebuild();
    return null;
  }

}
```

I added this snippt to the `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension 
        id="GenericProjectBuilder" 
        name="GenericProjectBuilder" 
        point="org.eclipse.core.resources.builders"> 
            <builder> 
                <run class="de.se_rwth.langeditor.global.GenericProjectBuilder"/>
            </builder> 
   </extension>
```

And if I add a new Project this method gets called to associate the project with the builder:

```
public static IProject getProject(IStorage storage) {
    if (storage instanceof IFile) {
      final String BUILDER_ID = "de.se_rwth.langeditor.global.GenericProjectBuilder";
      IProject project = ((IFile) storage).getProject();
      IProjectDescription desc;
      try {
        desc = project.getDescription();
        ICommand[] commands = desc.getBuildSpec();
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < commands.length; ++i) {
          if (commands[i].getBuilderName().equals(BUILDER_ID)) {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!found) { 
          //add builder to project
          ICommand command = desc.newCommand();
          command.setBuilderName(BUILDER_ID);
          ICommand[] newCommands = new ICommand[commands.length + 1];

          // Add it before other builders.
          System.arraycopy(commands, 0, newCommands, 1, commands.length);
          newCommands[0] = command;
          desc.setBuildSpec(newCommands);
          project.setDescription(desc, null);
        }
      }
      catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return ((IFile) storage).getProject();
    }
    else if (storage instanceof IJarEntryResource) {
      return ((IJarEntryResource) storage).getPackageFragmentRoot().getJavaProject().getProject();
    }
    else if (storage instanceof FileStorage) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown IStorage implementation - Please use: Import -> General -> Filesystem, to import file in workspace");
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown IStorage implementation");
    }
  }
```

But the `build`method is never called. Anything I missed out?

Comment: Is the builder appearing on the 'Builders' page of the project properties?

Comment: It says "Missing builder ("de.se_rwth.langeditor.global.GenericProjectBuilder")" for some reason

Comment: What is your plugin id? The builder you have defined in the plugin.xml has id 'plugin-id.GenericProjectBuilder'. Is that the same as 'de.se_rwth.langeditor.global.GenericProjectBuilder'?

Comment: ok I changed that, now the Builders page of project properties says GenericProjectBuilder as Builder, but the method is still not called

Comment: EDIT: Works like that, the wrong id was it, THANKS!